# ClassNotFoundException even after adding jar

Tags: java, android

I am getting org.sqlite.JDBC ClassNotFoundException in Eclipse.
I have added this jar in the build path. I have also extracted this jar and seen the org.sqlite.JDBC class and java file. Both are present in the mentioned package.

I have also tried downloading different versions of Jar, but issue is still occurring.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your `dist` folder for a reference to the jar? Have you created a `lib` folder? The jar must be available at run-time.

Comment: I have added the jar in lib folder as well. But now it is giving GC overhead limit error.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded/5640498#5640498

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your project `lib` folder. Adding to build path will help only at compile time. You need to add jar to runtime (one of the way to do this is, adding that particular Jar to lib folder)

Comment: Thanks but this also didn't work. Adding to lib folder gives GC overhead limit exception. What should I  do in this case? please suggest.